# how to compare two base64 string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a base64 string(source string) which was converted from an image, I need a code to compare that string with another base64 string on web service and check which string have the most similarities to the source string,the language I use is C#, can anyone help me ???

Comment: Are you attempting to determine if an image is an *exact* match, or a close match? You will only be able to determine *exact* matches by comparing base64 strings.

Comment: Please define what "the most similarities to the source string" mean. It may be [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but you've also mentioned images...

Comment: @cfeduke, question says "compare strings" so "similar" is possible too (but as you are pointing out it is probably not what OP wants).

Comment: what assumption are you making if comparing two base64 strings are a close match?

Comment: the string from web service was converted from image too, I want to compare 2 image, but I don't send an Image to web service, I convert that image to a base64 string to send and compare

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the strings easily, you could also save some bandwidth by using a MD5 checksum on each end.

Finding "most similarities" is up your algorithm implementation.  Only you know what "most similarities" means.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the total bits that are different, you can use something like this:

```
private long Base64BitsDifferent(string first64, string second64)
{
    long toReturn = 0;

    byte[] firstBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(first64);
    byte[] secondBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(second64);
    byte different = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < firstBytes.Length; index++) {
        different = (firstBytes[index] ^ secondBytes[index]);

        while (different != 0) {
            toReturn++;
            different &= different - 1;
        }
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Assuming the number of bytes represented in both Base64 strings are equal.